# Specific pattern as output with modulo operator

Tags: java, modulo

The task is to generate with **one** loop **and** the modulo-operator the following pattern.

12345
23451
34512
45123
51234

I do have a solution but i think it is not solved in a good way.
So i am looking for a more elegant way to solve the problem, without hurting the requirements.

```
class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num = 12345;
        System.out.println(num);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            int tmp = num%10000+21106+i;
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the meaning of the magic number 21106?

Comment: 12345%10000 = 2345; 

2345 + 21106 = 23451

Comment: so this magic number is useful for producing the 2nd line. what about the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract the first (most significant) digit with `/ 10000 and` the remaining digits with `% 10000`. Then you can construct the next number in the series.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num = 12345;
    System.out.println(num);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int first = num / 10000;
        int last4 = num % 10000;
        num = last4 * 10 + first;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for! I can mark solved in 8 minutes.

Comment: As i wrote, i can do it in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Eran's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889613/2970947) is correct, but hardcodes the order of the number (it will only work for numbers in the range 10000-99999). But, we can generalize it by noting that the length of a number (in decimal) is equal to the log<sub>10</sub> of the number. Something like

```
int num = 123456;
System.out.println(num);
int log10 = (int) Math.log10(num);
for (int i = 0; i < log10; i++) {
    int pow10 = (int) Math.pow(10, log10);
    int first = num / pow10;
    int last4 = num % pow10;
    num = last4 * 10 + first;
    System.out.println(num);
}
```